# Destructure property whose name is a reserverd keyword

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, destructuring

While using material ui, I realized they have a prop called `in` in the transitions components, but when trying to destruct the props, I can't because `in` is a reserved key word.

```
const MyFade = ({ children, in, ...otherProps }) => { // this gives me an error 
  return (
    <div {...otherProps}>
      <Fade in={in}>{children}</Fade>
    </div>
  );
};
```

How can I do this? I need to destruct `in` and have `otherProps` to spread in the `div`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just assign a new, not reserved name inside destructuring.

```js
const o = {
   in: 'foo',
   out: 'boo',
};

const { in: inProp } = o;
      // ^^^^ assign new name

console.log(inProp);
```